# what does return do in the run method of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In the run method I perform a boolean check to see if a log in was successful.

```
if (!logIn()) {
    return;
}
```

I had expected this to stop the run method, and the thread to finish, but it didnt?

Comment: but returning WILL end the thread.  If it didn't seem to in your case then the methodology you used to determine that was wrong.

Comment: In an Executor, returning will *not* necessarily end the thread. Did you submit your Runnable to an Executor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code *should* cause your thread to stop running, if it's directly in `Runnable.run()`.

If it doesn't, then you're doing something slightly different.

Comment: it does stop. i was running in android and forgot to upload the new code.

Answer (score 0):

The thread should terminate after `run()` is finished executing. Calling `return;` should terminate run(). Are you sure that your condition is actually true?